# I am gettting this error while running 'python3 wsgi.py' in flask python

Tags: python, flask

**Input:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Distance":windowsDistance})
bins = [0,70,200,350,500,650,800]
names = ['Ground Floor' , 'First Floor' , 'Second Floor' , 'Third Floor' , 'Fourth Floor' , 'Fifth Floor']
df['Output'] = pd.cut(windowsDistance,bins,labels=names)
print(df)
random_df={df}

return random_df
```

**Output:**
'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Because when I calling 'df' it will show error because it is dataframe so i can not call Dataframe in return

Comment: What error? Can you add the error message to the question? Can't you simply do `return df` ?